# Firebird .NET Provider GUID conversion

Tags: .net, firebird

I have a table with a primary key which is char(16) using the OCTETS char set.

It is filled with the contents of

```
select gen_uuid() from rdb$database
```

I have generated a dataset in VS. When I look at the data by choosing Preview in the tableadapter, it has converted it to hex.

Also the field type has been set to System.GUID.

Is this OK, i.e. is the firebird .net provider doing the conversion from OCTETS to HEX and if so will the value in the table be OK?

Regards

Comment: Seems like the best way to get the answer to this question is to just try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you put there `Guid`, .NET provider will convert the value to `char(16) octets` and vice versa - `char(16) octets` will be converted to `Guid` when reading.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. As I read it the question is: 1) does the .NET provider automatically convert `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS` to a GUID type, and 2) is this conversion correct?

Comment: Updated answer to make it clear. But still questioning (as @Tyler Jensen) why not to try it, right?

Comment: Is there any reason why the entity framework does not set the type to be System.Guid in the same way as a dataset?

Comment: http://blog.cincura.net/231978-seamless-support-for-boolean-and-guid-datatypes-in-firebird-and-entity-framework/

Comment: When I read Guid (stored as char(16) character set OCTETS) in database {5a0c4220-5731-4db5-b561-2626dc70d085}
then in code I have {20420c5a-3157-b54d-b561-2626dc70d085} -> first 8 bytes are reversed (order changed), why ?

Fb provider v5.9.1
Fb db v3.0.1